# How do I correctly use typeahead.js to autocomplete and retrieve data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typeahead.js

I have an old autocomplete.js code and with modification I tried to migrate it to typehead.js. The problem is I quite didn't find any results similar to angular and ajax.

Here's my script.

```
$('#empid').typeahead({

        minLength: 1,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({

                url: "http://localhost:2222/api/search/PostSearch",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{'eid':'" + document.getElementById('empid').value + "'}",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    response(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So How do I correctly do this. Help would be much appreciated.

Hi added the html script. Still couldn't let it to work. Can you help?

```
<script src="../../js/form-search.js"></script>
<!-- .page-content -->
<div ng-controller="SearchController" class="page-content clearfix">
    <!-- .page-content-wrapper -->
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content-inner">
            <!-- Start .page-content-inner -->
            <div id="page-header" class="clearfix">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Search Employee</h2>
                    <span class="txt">Search and manage employees</span>
                </div>
                <div class="header-stats">
                    <div class="spark clearfix">
                        <div class="spark-info"><span class="number">2345</span>Visitors</div>
                        <div id="spark-visitors" class="sparkline"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spark clearfix">
                        <div class="spark-info"><span class="number">17345</span>Views</div>
                        <div id="spark-templateviews" class="sparkline"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spark clearfix">
                        <div class="spark-info"><span class="number">3700$</span>Sales</div>
                        <div id="spark-sales" class="sparkline"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Start .row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <!-- col-lg-12 start here -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default plain toggle panelMove panelClose panelRefresh">
                        <!-- Start .panel -->
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">Basic Data tables</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label" for="">Employee id</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                                    <input id="empid" ng-model="searchedDetail.id" type="text" class="form-control" name="empid" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End .form-group  -->

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 control-label" for="">Employee name</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                                    <input  id="ename" ng-model="searchedDetail.ename" type="text" class="form-control" name="ename">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End .form-group  -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <button id="btnSearch" type="submit" ng-click="searchb()" class="btn btn-default pad">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <table id="basic-datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                        <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                                        <th>Gender</th>
                                        <th>email</th>
                                        <th>mobile no</th>
                                        <th>designation</th>
                                        <th>date of join</th>
                                        <th>nic</th>
                                        <th>department name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="emp in employes" style="text-align:center">
                                        <td>{{emp.fname}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.lname}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.DOB}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.gender}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.email}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.mobile_no}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.designation}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.date_of_join}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.nic}}</td>
                                        <td>{{emp.department_name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End .panel -->
                </div>
                <!-- col-lg-12 end here -->
            </div>
            <!-- End .row -->
        </div>
        <!-- End .page-content-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- / page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- / page-content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working solution

```
function BindEmployeeTypeAhead() {
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:2222/api/search/PostSearch",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: SuccessBindEmployeeTypeAhead,
        error: FailureBindEmployeeTypeAhead
    });
}
function SuccessBindEmployeeTypeAhead(response) {
    try {


        if (response == "")
            return;
        var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('EmployeeID', 'EmployeeName'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: JSON.parse(response)

        });

        dataSource.initialize();

        $("#empid").typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {

            display: function (item) {
                return item.EmployeeName //Name of property to be shown
            },
            source: dataSource.ttAdapter(),
            suggestion: function (data) {
                return '<div>' + data.EmployeeName + '–' + data.EmployeeID + '</div>'
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {

    }
}
function FailureBindEmployeeTypeAhead() {
}
```